# Can we create Kubernetes cluster with nodes from different Linux flavors?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to setup a kubernetes cluster with different flavors of Linux. Is it necessary to have both the nodes of the same Linux flavor? Is it possible to have kubernetes cluster consisting of one Ubuntu 14.04 and one CentOS 7 node? If yes how?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this link http://severalnines.com/blog/installing-kubernetes-cluster-minions-centos7-manage-pods-services it should be possible to run kubernetes minions on centos. This link same for Ubuntu: https://devops.profitbricks.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-a-multi-node-kubernetes-cluster-on-ubuntu/

Mixing different flavors of linux should not be a problem as far as i can see. Do create labels on your minions so your pods can select the appropriate minion to run on.